# How to turn off past over cell in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How to turn off past over cell in google sheet? to be very specific. I want to turn off the past value option in google sheet for Editor's that I am collaborating with.

Comment: There is not a way to limit if users can do a copy paste value unless you restrict them from doing any edits.

Comment: You can add in page permissions that lock certain cells if you don't want them to edit the specific cells. However, if they need to edit the cells in question, then this would not be a workable solution.